# sum between list's values by index

Tags: python-2.7, lambda, sum, reduce

I'm trying to sum a bunch of list by index, like:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]

output = [ reduce(lambda x, y: x[_count] + y[_count], a) 
           if _count in [0,2] else "" for _count in xrange(len(a)) ]
```

It must be right for me and the expected output is:

```
>>> output
[6, "", 12]
```

but i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Probably i'm not understanding reduce's engine.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you use `reduce` together with list comprehension?

Comment: I thought reduce would return a int and i need to iterate just to sum specific indexes. If there's something similiar, i'm all ears

Comment: hold on, how do you want to sum? `a[0][0]+a[0][1]+...` or `a[0][0]+a[1][0]+...`

Comment: Why are you trying to sum the indexes?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you use `reduce`. `reduce` works on a list as well and since it is a list of integers at least `y` in the lambda expression will thus be an `int`eger which is not scriptable (you cannot get `2[1]` for example).

You can however use `sum` and *list comprehension* for this:

```
output = [sum(ai) if i in (0,2) else "" for i,ai in enumerate(a)]
```

in case you want to sum the *transpose* (the two are thus **not** equivalent), you can also use a generator over the sum:

```
output = [sum(ai[i] for ai in a) if i in (0,2) else "" for i in range(len(a))]
```

Or if you want to calculate `a[0][0]+a[1][0]+a[2][0]+...` and so on, you can use `reduce`, the accumulator should start with `0` and you add `y[_count]` to `x` (not `x[_count]`):

```
from functools import reduce

output = [reduce(lambda x,y:x+y[i],a,0) if i in (0,2) else "" for i in range(len(a))]
```

Comment: That's it! I got it! Thank you so much. Just to know, why x + y[i] and not x[i] + y[i]?

Comment: @RenanQuirino: because `0` is the *accumulator*. Since it is stated that the initial value is `0` (third argument), in the first call `x` will be `0` and `y` the first list. So you calculate `t=0+a[0][0]`. The result `t` you pass as `x` the second time (again an `int`) and so on.